# Is there something better than $watch in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean

I am pretty new to Angularjs and I have a problem, that when I restart node sometimes some data goes missing. And I was thinking that it maybe comes from that page don't get db connection or data from db fast enough and overwrites some of the data.
Using mean stack and angularjs 1.x

I determined that this overwrite comes from that piece of code.

```
    landingTextService.getLandingText("workerTitle", "ee").then(function(data){
    if(data.text == null){
        $scope.workerTitle = {
            title: "There is nothing yet inserted"
        }

    }else{
        $scope.workerTitle = {
            title: data.text
        }
    }
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
})
$scope.$watch('workerTitle.title', function(val){
    landingTextService.addOrUpdateLandingText("workerTitle", val, "ee");
})
```

My first idea was to write these checks with ng-if to frontend so it wouldn't have to assign workertitle a new parameter.

Or I just would have to do second variable so it would be called out when it's null.

Check can't be == "", because they don't want text on banner sometimes.

Any advice how to fix it without rewriting everything or if I have to maybe some good article that explains why is that happening.

Comment: if youre using the MEAN stack, why arent you using angular 4/5?

Comment: I haven't done it from scratch. Been working with it for little over month.

Comment: so why arent you using the current technology? that itself could cause issues

Comment: First developer started it about year ago and he decided to go with angularjs 1.4.3 if I remember correctly. I honestly don't know why he decided to use it, after i upgraded it to 1.6.x I only saw white page with 1 background image. Fixed it by replacing succes with then and error with catch. And I don't know what will it do if i would upgrade it to angular 4.

Comment: plenty of people still use angular 1.x, "upgrading" to something else may not solve a problem that may be originating from human error

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, your opinionated idiosyncrasies are irrelevant and does not add anything to understanding the question or solve the problem. "*I have a problem with vue*" - "*why are you not using aurelia*" is just meaningless and destructive.

Comment: @davidkonrad they are not `idiosyncrasies`, angularJS is most likely going to have support dropped soon with sole focus on angular (2+) with it being built on the latest tech

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, there is no "latest tech" involved here, Angular is simply just another framework.

Comment: @davidkonrad however, i do not believe that angularjs conforms to webstandards anymore whereas angular does

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, the reality is quite the opposit, Angular breaks with almost each and every existing web standard.  But that is not the point, Angular is fine, and so is AngularJS. They are completely different frameworks, and therefore it does not make any sense to advocate for angular in the angularjs tag when you have a zillion questions you can debate and answer on the angular tag itself.

Comment: @davidkonrad no, angular changed from 1 -> 2 and "broke" lots, each revision after is to conform with web standards and add new features. the only real difference is that angularjs uses jquery (which is old now anyway) whereas angular doesnt

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, when I refer to "web standards" I refer to W3C standards, not whatever fancy stuff the Angular team implements. EOD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166395/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-davidkonrad).

Comment: So no help, thank you.